# Computer screen blinks at random intervals

Tags: hardware-failure

The screen on my laptop has started to flash black for about 50ms at random intervals. It's not related to any kind of movement it seems, and I think it's getting faster. It's a new enough laptop.

Sorry for the basic question, but how do I even go about debugging this?

**EDIT** I removed the HD and entered the BIOS screen, and the blinking doesn't happen there, which makes me think that it is almost 100% not a hardware problem unless it's a problem with the disk itself. I have tried to update my graphics drivers with no luck. My OS is Ubuntu 17.04 and the laptop is a Fujitsu Lifebook A

Comment: First of all I'd suggest to update OS, GPU drivers and laptop firmware. If it doesn't help, use Google (or your favourite search engine) and search for '"your laptop model" screen blink'. If you find something, apply suggested procedure. If you don't, apply the warranty.

Comment: @JaroslavKucera : That should be an answer.  I know, it sounds like simplistic advice.  But, it directly answers the asked question.

Comment: Consider that even though the flicker does not happen in BIOS - it still might be a hardware fault. Especially since power demand is much lower in BIOS. When you boot system, every component needs much more power and it must be sustained. It would be great if you could record this flicker with a camera and show it.

Answer (score 1):

The real question is if it flickers black or is it turning off black?

If it is flickering black but the power stays on for the screen I think you have a faulty cable between GPU/MOBO and screen or the GPU chip is failing. If it just turns black ie shuts down/poweroff - you have a problem with power supply.

To check which case is it for you, I would place a laptop in a dark room and wait for the flicker. Stand above the laptop to see the screen in steep angle - to observe the backlight - if backlight stays on it means the power supply to the screen is not a problem.

In both cases I would return the laptop on warranty if it is new. This should not be happening on a new laptop.

Comment: Hi @mnmnc, see edited question :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided any details, like your laptop model, used OS etc. Therefore I can only provide general hints I'd follow in your case:

First of all I'd suggest to update OS, GPU drivers and laptop firmware.

If it doesn't help, use Google (or your favourite search engine) and search for '"your laptop model" screen blink'.

If you find something, apply suggested procedure. If you don't, apply the warranty.

---

The best if you provide more info so our help can be a bit more specific.

Comment: Well, TOOGAM considers it answer too... I know it's basic, but based on available information, it's hard to provide something more, than generic hints.

Answer (score 0):

This flickering usually happens when the power being supplied to your computer drops suddenly.

Few things you can try to troubleshoot this problem-

- Whenever this happens, did you just open a program or anything like that?(This can include programs as simple as web browsers)

-Does your computer restart sometimes when this happens?

If any of the above seems to be your case, then it's an issue with the power supply. Try using another power cord.

Another possibility is a bad connection of the screen and the rest of the laptop. The fact that this problem is occurring more often and also that it's a new laptop suggests that this is a manufacturing defect and your usage is just worsening the issue.